# How to combine odds and evens into main id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have list of elements `odds` and `evens`. I want to combine all the odds and evens into `ID main` removing the nodes `odds` and `evens`.

I tried to achieve it like this:

```js
len = $('#odds').children().length + $('#evens').children().length;

for (var k = 1; k < len + 1; k++) {
  if (k % 2 != 0) {
    console.log('odds:', $('#odds').children()[0]);
    $('#main').append($('#odds').children()[0]);
  } else if (k % 2 == 0) {
    console.log('evens', $('#evens').children()[0]);
    $('#main').append($('#evens').children()[0])
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

</div>

<div id="odds">
  <div>sentence number one</div>
  <div>sentence number three</div>
  <div>sentence number five</div>
  <div>sentence number seven</div>
</div>

<div id="evens">
  <div>sentence number two</div>
  <div>sentence number four</div>
  <div>sentence number six</div>
</div>
```

I am able to get the output but the problem is I need to remove the kill the nodes/elements `odds` and `evens` after interleaving. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var odds = document.getElementById("odds").children;
var evens = document.getElementById("evens").children;
var main = document.getElementById("main");

var addOdd = true;

while(odds.length > 0 && evens.length > 0){
  if(addOdd){
   main.appendChild(odds[0]);
  }
  else{
   main.appendChild(evens[0]);
  }
  addOdd = !addOdd;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>

<div id="odds">
    <div>sentence number one</div>
    <div>sentence number three</div>
    <div>sentence number five</div>
    <div>sentence number seven</div>
</div>

<div id="evens">
    <div>sentence number two</div>
    <div>sentence number four</div>
    <div>sentence number six</div>
</div>
```

Note: you should make sure that you have enough evens and odds first.

Comment: Its ok I fixed it with `$('#odds, #evens').remove();` for looping.

Answer (score 0):

think this is what your looking to do :

```
function combine(){
  var main  = document.getElementById('main');
  var odds  = document.getElementById('odds');
  var evens = document.getElementById('evens');

  var combined = odds.innerHTML + evens.innerHTML

  main.innerHTML = combined;
  odds.innerHTML = "";
  evens.innerHTML = "";
}
combine()
```

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to interleave them, not just append them